# Hooking a kernel32 function with EasyHook

Tags: vb.net, windows, winapi, kernel32, easyhook

To hook a kernel function with EasyHook, do you need your own DLL that you made to be injected?

Comment: have you read [their documentation](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OldDocumentation&referringTitle=Documentation)?  You really need to show what you have tried and what doesn't work

Comment: Thats the problem, the only documentation I can find is http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/EasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking and it talks about a DLL to be injected, I will admit, I really have no idea what I'm doing, but I just want to be able to hook things like OpenProcess and find out when they're being called.

Comment: [this](http://www.ownedcore.com/forums/world-of-warcraft/world-of-warcraft-bots-programs/wow-memory-editing/299810-c-tutorial-how-become-endscene-hooker.html) might be useful?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need your own DLL that you want to inject. The idea is you need to write your own DLL to be injected and a host process. Your host process will inject your DLL inside the `kernel32.dll` or any other Windows DLL you are interested in to do the injection. Please read their [tutorial](https://easyhook.codeplex.com/downloads/get/623723), which contains a detailed description of the details.

Comment: How do you inject a DLL into kernel32.dll? You can inject a DLL into the process, and redirect calls/jmps from your target function to your DLL's code. You can't inject a dll into a dll.